# Does $A \cap (E_1\cup E_2) = [A\cap E_1]\cup [A\cap E_2\cap E_1^c]$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$A \cap (E_1\cup E_2) = [A\cap E_1]\cup [A\cap E_2\cap E_1^c]$$

Is this a correct relationship?
I tried not returned substantiated.
Thanks for all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is.

Use:

- $E_1 \cup E_2 = E_1 \cup (E_2\cap E_1^c)$;
- $A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$.

I leave the justification to you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: on the right hand side, consider $X=A\cap E_1$ , $Y=A\cap E_2$· Continue.